# Programmatically add both vertical and horizontal scroll in an activity

Tags: android, scroll

I have a tablelayout in an activity which contains header(column name), middle layout(column data) and a footer (button). Now i need a vertical scroll for middle layout and horizontal scroll for header and middle layout.

The vertical scroll for middle layout works fine but horizontal scroll is not working.

How can i add both way scroll in a single activity programmatically without using xml?

Here is my code so far.

```
RelativeLayout rlBody = new RelativeLayout(this);
rlBody.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bodyParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
rlBody.setLayoutParams(bodyParams);

but_downl = new Button(getApplicationContext());
but_downl.setText("Download");
but_downl.setWidth(width);

RelativeLayout footer = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams footerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

footerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
footer.setLayoutParams(footerParams);
footer.addView(but_downl);

RelativeLayout rlmaintableLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlmaintableLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
rlmaintableLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
rlmaintableLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, footer.getId());
rlmaintableLayout.setLayoutParams(rlmaintableLayoutParams);

TableLayout maintableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
maintableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

TextView tvQnr, tvDownLType, tvPublishBy, tvPublishDate, tvMonPlan, tvLang, textViewMsg;
CheckBox chk, chkparent;
View v;
tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

v = new View(this);
v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));

chkparent=new CheckBox(this);
tableRow.addView(chkparent);

tvQnr=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvQnr.setText("Name");
tvQnr.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
tvQnr.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvQnr.setTextSize(20);
tvQnr.setPadding(20, 20, 30, 20);
tableRow.addView(tvQnr);

tvDownLType=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvDownLType.setText("Age");
tvDownLType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
tvDownLType.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvDownLType.setTextSize(20);
tvDownLType.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
tableRow.addView(tvDownLType);

tvPublishBy=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvPublishBy.setText("Gender");
tvPublishBy.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
tvPublishBy.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvPublishBy.setTextSize(20);
tvPublishBy.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
tableRow.addView(tvPublishBy);

tvPublishDate=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvPublishDate.setText("Published Date");
tvPublishDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
tvPublishDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvPublishDate.setTextSize(20);
tvPublishDate.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
tableRow.addView(tvPublishDate);

tvMonPlan=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvMonPlan.setText("Roll No");
tvMonPlan.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
tvMonPlan.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvMonPlan.setTextSize(20);
tvMonPlan.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
tableRow.addView(tvMonPlan);

tvLang=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tvLang.setText("Language");
tvLang.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
tvLang.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
tvLang.setTextSize(20);
tvLang.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
tableRow.addView(tvLang);

maintableLayout.addView(tableRow);
maintableLayout.addView(v);

RelativeLayout scrollHolder = new RelativeLayout(this);        
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollHolderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

scrollHolder.setLayoutParams(scrollHolderParams);

ScrollView myScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
myScrollView.setEnabled(true); 

HorizontalScrollView horscrollview = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
horscrollview.setEnabled(true);

TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
int cnt = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < myFormresult.size(); j++){
    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    v = new View(this);
    v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));

    cnt = cnt + 1;
    chk = new CheckBox(this);

    tvQnr = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvQnr.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    tvQnr.setTextSize(15);
    tvQnr.setText(myFormresult.get(j).getFormName());
    tvQnr.setPadding(25, 10, 20, 10);

    tvDownLType = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvDownLType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    tvDownLType.setTextSize(15);
    tvDownLType.setText(myFormresult.get(j).getVersion());
    tvDownLType.setPadding(25, 10, 20, 10);

    tvPublishBy = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvPublishBy.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    tvPublishBy.setTextSize(15);
    tvPublishBy.setText(myFormresult.get(j).getPublishedBy());
    tvPublishBy.setPadding(25, 10, 20, 10);

    tvPublishDate = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvPublishDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    tvPublishDate.setTextSize(15);
    tvPublishDate.setText(myFormresult.get(j).getPublishedDate());
    tvPublishDate.setPadding(25, 10, 20, 10);

    tvMonPlan = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvMonPlan.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    tvMonPlan.setTextSize(15);
    tvMonPlan.setText(myFormresult.get(j).getMonitoringPlan());
    tvMonPlan.setPadding(25, 10, 20, 10);

    tvLang = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tvLang.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    tvLang.setTextSize(15);
    tvLang.setText(myFormresult.get(j).getLanguage());
    tvLang.setPadding(25, 10, 20, 10);          

    tableRow.addView(chk);  
    tableRow.addView(tvQnr);
    tableRow.addView(tvDownLType);
    tableRow.addView(tvPublishBy);
    tableRow.addView(tvPublishDate);
    tableRow.addView(tvMonPlan);
    tableRow.addView(tvLang);                

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    tableLayout.addView(v);
    tableLayout.addView(vertView);
}


if (cnt == 0) {
    textViewMsg = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textViewMsg.setText("No records found ...");
    textViewMsg.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#235C8B"));
    textViewMsg.setTextSize(15);
    tableLayout.addView(textViewMsg);
    but_downl.setEnabled(false);
}


myScrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 

horscrollview.addView(tableLayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

myScrollView.addView(horscrollview);

scrollHolder.addView(myScrollView);
maintableLayout.addView(scrollHolder);
rlmaintableLayout.addView(maintableLayout);
rlBody.addView(rlmaintableLayout);
rlBody.addView(footer);
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Can you post you code? what do you mean by `but horizontal scroll is not working.`

Comment: I have posted my code. vertical scroll was working fine but when i add the horizontal scroll, the middle layout disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I was created table layout with horizontal and vertical scrolling. Also header is fixed at vertical scrolling.

I sent you code of class and xml file you can customize it according your requirement.
I hope it will help you.

Create MainActivity Class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 HorizontalScrollView hori,hori2;
 int viewWidth;
 TableLayout scrollablePart;
 GestureDetector gestureDetector = null;
 ArrayList<LinearLayout> layouts;
  LinearLayout linear;
    private int scrollMax;
 int currPosition, prevPosition;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableRow.LayoutParams wrapWrapTableRowParams = new          TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int[] fixedColumnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20};
    int[] scrollableColumnWidths = new int[]{20,20, 20, 20, 20, 20};
    int fixedRowHeight = 50;
    int fixedHeaderHeight = 60;

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    //header (fixed horizontally)

    TableLayout fixedColumn = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_column);
    TableLayout fixedColumn2 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixed_header_column);
    TextView fixedView2 = makeTableRowWithText("col 1 ", scrollableColumnWidths[0], fixedRowHeight);
    fixedView2.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    fixedColumn2.addView(fixedView2);

    //rest of the table (within a scroll view)

     scrollablePart = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollable_part);

    //header (fixed vertically)
     hori=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizon);
     hori.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
     hori.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
     hori2=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.hr_2);
           //hori.onScrollChanged
     hori2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            moveScrollView();
            cal();

            //startAutoScrolling(); 
            return false;
        }
    });
    ScrollView scrol=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Scroll);
    //scrol.onScrollChanged(fixedHeaderHeight, fixedHeaderHeight, fixedHeaderHeight, fixedHeaderHeight);

     linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fillable_area);

    TableLayout header = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_header);
    //scrollablePart.onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = linear.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            linear.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            getScrollMaxAmount();

        }
    });
    hori2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            moveScrollView();
            //startAutoScrolling(); 
            return false;
        }
    });
    row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 2", fixedColumnWidths[1], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 3", fixedColumnWidths[2], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 4", fixedColumnWidths[3], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 5", fixedColumnWidths[4], fixedHeaderHeight));
    row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("col 6", fixedColumnWidths[5], fixedHeaderHeight));
    header.addView(row);


    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        TextView fixedView = makeTableRowWithText("row number " + i, scrollableColumnWidths[0], fixedRowHeight);
        fixedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        fixedColumn.addView(fixedView);
        row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(wrapWrapTableRowParams);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 2", scrollableColumnWidths[1], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 3", scrollableColumnWidths[2], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 4", scrollableColumnWidths[3], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 5", scrollableColumnWidths[4], fixedRowHeight));
        row.addView(makeTableRowWithText("value 6", scrollableColumnWidths[5], fixedRowHeight));
        scrollablePart.addView(row);
    }
}
    private void cal(){     
 final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
             int i=0;
      public void run()
      {                                     
       if(i==0)
        {      
          try{                   
              moveScrollView();
             }catch (Exception e){
           }           
          i++;
        }
        handler2.postDelayed(this,500);
      }
     };   
       handler2.postDelayed(runnable, 500); 
    }    
    public void getScrollMaxAmount(){
    int actualWidth = (linear.getMeasuredWidth()-512);
    scrollMax   = actualWidth;


    System.out.println("scrollMax"+scrollMax);
}
    private Timer scrollTimer       =   null;
private Timer clickTimer        =   null;
private Timer faceTimer         =   null;
private TimerTask clickSchedule;
private TimerTask scrollerSchedule;
private TimerTask faceAnimationSchedule;
private int scrollPos = 0;
public void startAutoScrolling(){
    if (scrollTimer == null) {
        scrollTimer                 =   new Timer();
        final Runnable Timer_Tick   =   new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                moveScrollView();
            }
        };

        if(scrollerSchedule != null){
            scrollerSchedule.cancel();
            scrollerSchedule = null;
        }
        scrollerSchedule = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
            }
        };

        scrollTimer.schedule(scrollerSchedule, 30, 30);
    }
}
public void moveScrollView(){
    scrollPos                           =   (int) (hori.getScrollX() + 1.0);
    scrollPos                           =   (int) (hori2.getScrollX() + 1.0);
    System.out.println("scrollPos"+scrollPos);

    if(scrollPos >= scrollMax){
        scrollPos = 0;
    }
    hori2.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
    hori.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);

}  

private TextView recyclableTextView;
 public TextView makeTableRowWithText(String text, int widthInPercentOfScreenWidth, int   fixedHeightInPixels) {
int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
recyclableTextView = new TextView(this);
recyclableTextView.setText(text);
recyclableTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
recyclableTextView.setTextSize(20);
recyclableTextView.setWidth(widthInPercentOfScreenWidth * screenWidth / 100);
recyclableTextView.setHeight(fixedHeightInPixels);
return recyclableTextView;
 }
}
```

Create activity_main.xmml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/fillable_area">
<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/fillable_area1">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixed_header_column"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/Scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/fillable_area">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixed_column"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hr_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```